# Radiobutton add class when checked, removeclass when not checked

Tags: jquery, css

Can you guys help me. I want to add the class 'checked' to the span with class '.group_4'. I figured i'd use jquery. I can't change the HTML.

What happens now is: when clicking on both items, the class is not removed. So both spans have the class "gechecked".

Any easy solution?

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".attribute_list label").click(function() {
    if ($('input.attribute_radio').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).find('.group_4').addClass("gechecked");
    } else {
      $(this).find('.group_4').removeClass("gechecked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="attribute_list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label><div class="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="checked"><input style="display:none !important" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="25"></span></div>
                <span class="group_4 gechecked">Graniet</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><div class="radio" style="display: none;"><span class=""><input style="display:none !important" type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_4" value="26" checked="checked"></span></div>
                <span class="group_4 gechecked">Composiet</span></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the class from _all_ relevant elements first, before you set it for the current one …?

Comment: If you just have 2 radio buttons, you could also try to use the toggleClass :)

Comment: @Jacob your html does not match your requriement.Are you sure that you can't change your html

Comment: Removing the class seems to be the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02jk38wd/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".attribute_list label").click(function() {
    $('.group_4').removeClass("gechecked");
    if ($('input.attribute_radio').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).find('.group_4').addClass("gechecked");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".attribute_list label").click(function() {
        $(this).find('.group_4').removeClass("gechecked");          
        $('input.attribute_radio:checked').parent().parent().parent().find('.group_4').addClass("gechecked");
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".attribute_list label").click(function() {
    $('.group_4').removeClass("gechecked");
    if ($('input.attribute_radio').is(':checked')) {
      $(this).find('.group_4').addClass("gechecked");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.